# How to add a system call to find the number of processes in xv6

Tags: unix, operating-system, system-calls, xv6

I have added this function in **proc.c** file

```c
int getNumProc(void)
{
  struct proc *p;
  int count = 0;

  acquire(&ptable.lock);

  for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++)
  {
     if(p->state != UNUSED)
        count++;
  }

  release(&ptable.lock);

 return count;
}
```

I have made all the necessary modifications in the following files:

1. defs.h
2. sysproc.c
3. syscall.h
4. usys.S
5. syscall.c
6. user.h

I also created a  user program called **`totproc.c`** to call this system call and added this user program in `Makefile` at relevant places. When I type **`totproc`** command in XV6 shell the command does print that  there a 3 processes. But alongside the result, it also prints the following error :

**`pid 4 totproc: trap 14 err 5 on cpu 1 eip 0xffffffff addr 0xffffffff--kill proc`**

What could be wrong here? If you were to write a system call to find the number of processes, how would you write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I figured out the problem. Turned out , the problem was not in my system call but in the user program **`totproc.c`** that made the system call. My initial  **`totproc.c`** looked like this :

```c
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

int main()
{
  printf(1 , "No. of Process: %d" , getNumProc());
  return 0;
}
```

The properly working **`totproc.c`** is like below :

```c
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "fcntl.h"

int main()
{
  printf(1 , "No. of Process: %d" , getNumProc());
  exit();
}
```

Comment: However , I don't seem to understand why the second totproc.c worked. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In xv6, all userspace applications must use exit() and not simply return from main. This behavior occur because when xv6 builds a new process' stack (in the exec system call implementation) the "return address" from main is set to 0xFFFFFFFF which is an not a valid userspace address to reach, which in turn, causes the MMU to return page fault.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be in the right way but looks like you are missing something.

The error you are getting is being produced when an unexpected interrupt is received (in trap.c). Specifically, trap number 14 is T_PGFLT (according to trap.h).
This means the MMU answered with a page fault interrupt when some address was being tried to access, in other words, you are probably having a memory overwrite or access violation somewhere.

Consider sharing you user space application code.

Comment: Do you have any idea why my second totproc.c worked ?